# Get XML namespace text via SQL query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, xml-namespaces

I am working with XML data on an SQL Server. The (exemplary) SQL looks as follows:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns">
  <Testnode>a</Testnode>
</Document>
```

The XML is available in a table with a column named `<fata` of type `XML`.

**My question is:** How can I create a SELECT query that shows the text of the namespace in one column?

The expected output should be:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| xmlns                                  |
+----------------------------------------+
| urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

The result column should be a character string (no XML).

So far I have tried this query, however the result is `NULL`:

```
SELECT Data.value('(./Document)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS xmlns
FROM xmltable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something along this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns">
  <Testnode>a</Testnode>
</Document>';
```

--The XQuery-function `namespace-uri()` takes a singleton and returns its namespace uri

```
SELECT @xml.value('namespace-uri((/*:Document)[1])','nvarchar(max)');
```

As the `<Document>` element is living within the default namespace itself, we would have to know the namespace in advance in order to declare it. But - luckily - we can use the wildcard with `*:`.

Another option - one of the rare cases - is the usage of the outdated `FROM OPENXML`:

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns">
  <Testnode>a</Testnode>
</Document>';

DECLARE @docHandle INT;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xml;  
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, '/*',1);  
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle;
```

This returns the complete XML with a lot of meta-data:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | parentid | nodetype | localname | prefix | namespaceuri                          | datatype | prev | text                                  |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
| 0  | NULL     | 1        | Document  | NULL   | urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                  |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
| 2  | 0        | 2        | xmlns     | xmlns  | NULL                                  | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                  |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
| 4  | 2        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL                                  | NULL     | NULL | urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
| 3  | 0        | 1        | Testnode  | NULL   | urn:iso:std:iso:20022:some:test:xmlns | NULL     | NULL | NULL                                  |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
| 5  | 3        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL                                  | NULL     | NULL | a                                     |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+
```